# matplotlib from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot - ylim control of right axis?

Tags: matplotlib

The focus of my question pertains to getting control over the right hand side y-axis limits.  The code:

```
if y2_lim != None:
    par2.set_ylim(y2_lim)
```

Has no affect before or after the plot call.  I am stumped.  Any input help would be greatly appreciated, especially an explanation of why it doesn't work.  This type of conundrum happens too often with Matplotlib.  Thanks, Charles

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotTwoAxis(aData1, aData2, anXLabel, aY1Label, aY2Label, aTitle, 
                aSubtitle, aLegend1Label, aLegend2Label, y1_lim = None, y2_lim = None):

host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)

par1 = host.twinx()
par2 = host.twinx()

offset = 60
new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
par2.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right",
                                    axes=par2,
                                    offset=(offset, 0))

par2.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)

host.set_xlim(0, 24)

host.set_xlabel(anXLabel)
host.set_ylabel(aY1Label)
par1.set_ylabel(aY2Label)

if y1_lim != None:
    par1.set_ylim(y1_lim)
if y2_lim != None:
    par2.set_ylim(y2_lim)

p1, = host.plot(time, aData1, label=aLegend1Label)
p2, = par1.plot(time, aData2, label=aLegend2Label)

host.legend()

host.axis["left"].label.set_color(p1.get_color())
par1.axis["right"].label.set_color(p2.get_color())

plt.title(aTitle + aSubtitle)

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank - you for your consideration.  The set_ylim should occur after the plot call.  Also, the limits need to be set on par1 rather than par2.  The plots work as advertised.

Comment: What do you mean "the limits need to be set on par1 rather than par2"? That `y1_lim` is the bottom limit of the axis, and `y2_lim` is the top limit? Plase be _specific_ - a vague question gives a vague answer with assumptions etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have only provided the `bottom` argument to the [`set_ylim`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim) method. Also, you should call the `set_ylim` method after the plots if you haven't disabled the autoscale of the axes. If you want the bottom limit of the y-axes to default to 0, then uo can modify your code like this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotTwoAxis(aData1, aData2, anXLabel, aY1Label, aY2Label, aTitle, 
                aSubtitle, aLegend1Label, aLegend2Label,
                y1_bottom = 0, y1_lim = None, # bottom and top limits respectively
                y2_bottom = 0, y2_lim = None): # bottom and top limits, respectively

    host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)

    par1 = host.twinx()
    par2 = host.twinx()

    offset = 60
    new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
    par2.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right",
                                    axes=par2,
                                    offset=(offset, 0))

    par2.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)

    host.set_xlim(0, 24)

    host.set_xlabel(anXLabel)
    host.set_ylabel(aY1Label)
    par1.set_ylabel(aY2Label)

    p1, = host.plot(time, aData1, label=aLegend1Label)
    p2, = par1.plot(time, aData2, label=aLegend2Label)

    if y1_lim != None:
        par1.set_ylim(y1_bottom, y1_lim)
    if y2_lim != None:
        par2.set_ylim(y2_bottom, y2_lim)

    host.legend()

    host.axis["left"].label.set_color(p1.get_color())
    par1.axis["right"].label.set_color(p2.get_color())

    plt.title(aTitle + aSubtitle)

    plt.draw()
    plt.show()
```

This makes an output with the desired y-limits:

```
import numpy as np

time = np.arange(25)

plotTwoAxis(np.random.rand(25),
            np.random.rand(25),
            'x label 1', 'y label 1', 'y label 2','Title', ' Subtitle',
            'Plot 1','Plot 2', y1_lim = 0.5, y2_lim = 0.75 )
```

[image]

---

On a side note; is this the behavior you want with respect to the title and subtitle?